# Why do I sometimes get new apps that I have not installed when I boot my laptop?

Tags: boot, appmenu

So when I start my Ubuntu 20.04 laptop I eventually get some new apps like this one **''ImageMagick''** that I'm 100% sure that I did not install and many others that I don't even remember to the point that probably half of all my apps idk what they even do. Help me.

[image]

Comment: There are a number of apps shipped by default when installing ubuntu... You can check which by using a live DVD or USB and checking there...

Comment: Please add output of `dpkg -l | grep -i imagemagick` along with `grep -ri imagemagick /usr/share/applications --include=*.desktop`.

Comment: Try `apt rdepends imagemagick | grep Depends`. Every application on the resulting list *must* pull in imagemagick as a dependency.

Answer (score 2):

Additional applications will never automatically be added. They will only be added after installing a package yourself.

The icon you see is from ImageMagick, mainly a batch image processing software for the command line with a graphical tool, for which a launcher is installed. It is there because you installed the `imagemagic` package, or because you installed some other application that has automatically installed `imagemagic` as a dependency or recommended package.

For example, one can see what packages need or suggest `imagemagic` with the command:

```
apt-cache rdepends imagemagick | less
```

Packages listed include `libreoffice`, `videotrans`, `playonlinux`, `xpaint`

Answer (score 2):

You probably installed some application that required ImageMagick as a dependency. So it was installed and you see it in the launcher.

I know that `playonlinux` installs `imagemagick` as an example.

This is normal.